# Correct voweling of Birkat Hamazon

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, bentching

Most of my Hebrew knowledge comes from Biblical Hebrew, and when i read most Ashkenazi siddurim i'm usually on board with how they decide to vowelize things. However, being Sephardic, and wanting an abridged Birkat Hamazon, i found the one of Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi to be preferable since it follows the nusach of the Rambam. Most of the voweling looks great, but one particular paragraph looks very off and i don't know if it's because this particular prayer is Mishnaicized, or if i'm ignorant of some other rules. So here is an image that has Rabbi Abadi's version on the right, and a version i've edited on the left.

Is Rabbi Abadi's version correct? And if so, why? (And if mine is in error could someone please point them out?)

[image]

Comment: Did R Abadi publish that app?

Comment: @DoubleAA i got it from the Android App Birkat HaKatzar which is "published" by David Fassey but in the commentions mentions that Rabbi Abadi says to use this blessing for birkat hamazon

Comment: @Aaron I was being facetious. It does not accurately represent the vowels as in R Abadi's own printed responsum on the matter. Mr. Fassey it seems has erred.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the printed responsum? i was originally going off this version, but the vowels there seem corrupted as well: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=63

Comment: In truth, both versions have an error: it should be עַמָּךְ or עַמֶּךָ with a regular _patah_, not a _hataf patah_.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted wording and vowelization for the Edoth HaMizrach is:

> רַחֵם * *  עָלֵינוּ וְעַל יִשְׂרָאֵל **עַמָּךְ**. וְעַל יְרוּשָׁלַיִם **עִירָךְ**. וְעַל הַר צִיּוֹן מִשְׁכַּן כְּבוֹדָךְ וְעַל הֵיכָלָךְ. וְעַל מְעוֹנָךְ. וְעַל דְּבִירָךְ. וְעַל הַבַּיִת הַגָּדוֹל וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ שֶׁנִּקְרָא שִׁמְךָ עָלָיו

The accepted wording and vowelization for Ashkenazim is:

> רַחֶם נָא * * עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל **עַמֶּךָ**. וְעַל יְרוּשָׁלַיִם **עִירֶךָ**. וְעַל צִיּוֹן מִשְׁכַּן כְּבוֹדֶךָ. וְעַל מַלְכוּת בֵּית דָּוִד מְשִׁיחֶךָ. וְעַל הַבַּיִת הַגָּדוֹל וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ שֶׁנִּקְרָא שִׁמְךָ עָלָיו

It seems to me like the app has a badly edited version, from trying to convert one into the other while creating the abridged version.

Comment: Your last comment was my thought too (courtesy ping, @Aaron)